# How may I allow function to access all the variables in loop and execute them using javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am a newbie to JavaScript.

I have been trying to make a small multiplication drill using math random, loop and function.

The loop displays all the variables but the fuction only operates and displays the last values of variables when I click my check button.

My script is as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Multiplication Drill</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">check </button>

<p id="demo1"> </p>
<script>
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i <3; i++) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  text += x+ " " + "x" + " "+ y + " " + "="+"<br>";
  
  function myFunction(){
  var z = x*y;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = z;
  }
}
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose it's got something to do with wrapping the x and y into arrays or objects. I have tried using curly brackets and square brackets, I have tried many ways.

How may I allow the function to access all the variables in the loop and operate them?

Thanks a lot for the time and attention.

Comment: Can you better explain (w/ example(s), perhaps?) what you want this to do?

Comment: `myFunction` is never called.

Comment: @Scott Hunter<br/>Here it is <br/>'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"> </p>
<button onclick ="myFunction()"> check</button>

<p id="demo1"> </p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i <3; i++) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  text += x+ " " + "x" + " "+ y + " " + "="+"<br>";
  
  function myFunction(){
  var z = x*y;
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = z;
  }

}
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>'

Comment: @Scott Hunter  I am sorry. I am new. I am still bad at using the syntax for commenting.

Comment: @Tanopin btw, if my answer is correct, could u pls mark :D

Comment: @  The Bomb Squad. What I meant is if we run it, there are multiplication questions given without answers. Once we press the check button, all the answers are given (without deleting or changing the questions but only displaying the answers under the check button).

Answer (score 1):

Were you trying to do this?

**EDIT**: I saw the code you put in the comments so I copied the html, pressed enter a few times to make it indented(and not one continuous line, dw the site did that to what you pasted) and now that the `onclick` was the function, creating the function in the **scope** of the while loop was what was wrong. In this case the function was **all the things** you wanted to do so I made the function surround the solution and *voila*

```js
function myFunction(){
  var text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    text += x+ " " + "x" + " "+ y + " " + "="+" "+x*y+"\n";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText=text;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="demo"> </p> 
   <button onclick ="myFunction()"> check</button>
   <p id="demo1"> </p>  
</body>
</html>
```

For a raw copy paste, look below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="demo"> </p> 
   <button onclick ="myFunction()"> check</button>
   <p id="demo1"> </p>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  var text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    text += x+ " " + "x" + " "+ y + " " + "="+" "+x*y+"\n";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText=text;
}
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"> </p>
<button onclick ="myFunction()"> check</button>

<p id="demo1"> </p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i <3; i++) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  text += x+ " " + "x" + " "+ y + " " + "="+"<br>";
  
  function myFunction(){
  var z = x*y;
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = z;
  }

}
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My bad.  I am new here.  I have to learn a lot how to use to the code in commenting.

Comment: @Tanopin no worries, check my edited answer now >:D